# Is it possible to call directly from a model method from another model of the same component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

Is it possible to call directly from a model method from another model of the same component?

Is there any default Joomla option to call in such a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can

It will not break MVC architecture,

You can check like this

```
if(!class_exists('VirtueMartModelUser')) require(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'models'.DS.'user.php');

            $usermodel = VmModel::getModel('user');

            $currentVMuser = $usermodel->getUser();
```

First you should include the model file in the required model then create the object.
then call like above.
This example is Virtue-mart using method

Answer (score 0):

According to the my knowledge **NO**. Otherwise it will break the MVC architecture.

What you can do is

- Replicate the function you want to use.
- Make the call from the controller to the both method.

My Advice is to you is even if you figure out a way to do it, Don't do it. It will mess up your whole architecture.

If you have any issues please ask.

Comment: Yes we can do that it will not break MVC.

Comment: according to my knowledge we never call a model inside a model. Instead controller handles all the calls.

Comment: Yes,But you can also do that.just the concept of class inside class its not braking any mvc strcuture

Comment: We don't usually use class inside a class according to oop

Comment: Ok but it is possible and VM is using that its huge shopping cart !

Comment: I'm not quite sure about VM using it. I what told you is the standard. It's totally up to you whether to use it or not.